# Cell coloring does not work properly in tables

Tags: tables, color, alignment, highlighting

I have a table that I would like to color/highlight its rows. I am using `\cellcolor` function but have no idea why it is not working properly. Also, please help me to locate "Normal" and "High" exactly in the middle of the first column. Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison of performance metrics for heuristic scheduling rules}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l l l l l}
    \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Inst.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Demand} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heuristic scheduling rules} \\ \cline{3-7}
                               &  & Myopic & PPQ & DMB & AOP & EPPQ \\\hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{Normal} & \cellcolor{gray!30}1    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{34.1 \\ $[4.6, 0, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30} \makecell[l]{\color{blue}{11.4} \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30} \makecell[l]{18.2 \\ $[2.8, 0, 0.6]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.5 \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.5 \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} \\
                                & 2    & \makecell[l]{84.7 \\ $[6.6, 0, 3.4]$} & \makecell[l]{44.0 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$} & \makecell[l]{44.1 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$} & \makecell[l]{42.8 \\ $[2.2, 0, 1.7]$} & \makecell[l]{44.3 \\ $[2.9, 0, 3.2]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}3        & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{124.6 \\ $[7.5, 11.7, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{47.3 \\ $[3.8, 6.7, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{51.9 \\ $[4.1, 7.3, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.8 \\ $[2.3, 0.6, 0.3]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{12.4 \\ $[2.4, 1.0, 0.4]$} \\
                               &  4    & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\
                               &  \cellcolor{gray!30}5    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\\hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{High} & 1    & \makecell[l]{138.0 \\ $[6.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.3 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.7 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$} & \makecell[l]{79.5 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.8 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}2    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{104.96 \\ $[6.8, 0, 6.0]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.5 \\ $[2.9, 0, 4.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.6 \\ $[3.0, 0, 4.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{59.9 \\ $[2.6, 0, 3.9]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.0 \\ $[2.9, 0, 4.5]$} \\
                                & 3        &  \makecell[l]{225.5 \\ $[8.9, 16.6, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{154.5 \\ $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{154.7 \\ $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{83.0 \\ $[2.9, 4.6, 2.3]$} & \makecell[l]{79.2 \\ $[3.0, 4.5, 2.1]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}4    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\
                                &  5    & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\makecell[l]{Performance metrics consist of the immediate cost and [wait time of scheduled patients, number of \\ referrals, number of rejections] - average values.}}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tabCOM}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White strips in colored cells are caused by use of `makecell` in ceLls. Removing them, using `tabularx` table environment (that table is not wider than text) solve your problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Comparison of performance metrics for heuristic scheduling rules}
    \label{tabCOM}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|c| *{5}{X}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Inst.} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{Demand} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heuristic scheduling rules}    \\   \cline{3-7}
            &   & Myopic    & PPQ   & DMB   & AOP   & EPPQ  \\  \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & 1    
        &   34.1\par $[4.6, 0, 0.2]$ 
            &   \textcolor{blue}{11.4}\par $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$
                &  18.2\par $[2.8, 0, 0.6]$
                    &   11.5\par $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$
                        &   11.5\par $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$        \\
    & 2 &   84.7\par $[6.6, 0, 3.4]$
            &   44.0\par $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$
                &   44.1\par $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$
                    &   42.8\par $[2.2, 0, 1.7]$  
                        &   44.3\par $[2.9, 0, 3.2]$         \\
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    &   &   124.6\par $[7.5, 11.7, 0.2]$
            &   47.3\par $[3.8, 6.7, 0.2]$
                &   51.9\par $[4.1, 7.3, 0.2]$
                    &   11.8\par $[2.3, 0.6, 0.3]$
                        &   12.4\par $[2.4, 1.0, 0.4]$      \\
    & 4 &   ~\par $[, , ]$ 
            &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                    &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                        &   ~\par $[, , ]$                  \\
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow{-10}{*}{Normal}
    & 5 &   ~\par $[, , ]$
            &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                &   ~\par $[, , ]$  
                    &   ~\par $[, , ]$  
                        &   ~\par $[, , ]$              \\
    \hline
    & 1 &   138.0\par $[6.9, 0, 2.6]$
            &   79.3\par $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$
                &   79.7\par $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$
                    &   79.5\par $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$
                        &   79.8\par $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$    \\
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & 2 &   104.96   $[6.8, 0, 6.0]$
            &   61.5     $[2.9, 0, 4.4]$
                &   61.6\par $[3.0, 0, 4.4]$
                    &   59.9\par $[2.6, 0, 3.9]$
                        &   61.0\par $[2.9, 0, 4.5]$     \\
    & 3 &   225.5\par $[8.9, 16.6, 2.2]$
            &   154.5\par $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$ 
                &   154.7\par $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$
                    &   83.0\par $[2.9, 4.6, 2.3]$
                        &   79.2\par $[3.0, 4.5, 2.1]$      \\
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
\cellcolor{white}
    & 4 &   ~\par $[, , ]$
            &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                    &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                        &   ~\par $[, , ]$                   \\
\multirow{-10}{*}{High}
    & 5 &   ~\par $[, , ]$
            &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                    &   ~\par $[, , ]$
                        &   ~\par $[, , ]$                   \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}{Performance metrics consist of the immediate cost and [wait time of scheduled patients, number of referrals, number of rejections] - average values.}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: first example]

(red lines indicate text borders)

**Addendum:**
The solution which use `tabularray` package with defining a bit more sophisticated way for rows coloring in table preamble. Consequently table's body code is simpler. Beside this cells contents is beter vertical positioned:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{teal}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\ExplSyntaxOn   % rule for table coloring
\NewChildSelector{eachtwocolor}
  {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\caption{Comparison of performance metrics for heuristic scheduling rules}
    \label{tabCOM}

\begin{tblr}{row{eachtwocolor} = {bg=red!15},   % set color of your choice
             row{Z} = {bg=white},
             colspec  = {Q[l, bg=white] |c| *{5}{X[l]}},
             hspan=minimal,
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Inst.
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Demand
        &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Heuristic scheduling rules
            &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \midrule
    &   & Myopic    & PPQ   & DMB   & AOP   & EPPQ  \\
    \midrule[0.7pt]
\SetCell[r=5]{c}   Normal
    & 1 &   {34.1\\  $[4.6, 0, 0.2]$}
            &  { \textcolor{blue}{11.4}\\  $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$}
                &  {18.2\\  $[2.8, 0, 0.6]$}
                    &   {11.5\\  $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$}
                        &   {11.5\\  $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$}      \\
    & 2 &   {84.7\\  $[6.6, 0, 3.4]$}
            &   {44.0\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$}
                &   {44.1\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$}
                    &   {42.8\\  $[2.2, 0, 1.7]$}
                        &   {44.3\\  $[2.9, 0, 3.2]$}      \\
    & 3 &   {124.6\\  $[7.5, 11.7, 0.2]$}
            &   {47.3\\  $[3.8, 6.7, 0.2]$}
                &   {51.9\\  $[4.1, 7.3, 0.2]$}
                    &   {11.8\\  $[2.3, 0.6, 0.3]$}
                        &   {12.4\\  $[2.4, 1.0, 0.4]$}      \\
    & 4 &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
            &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                    &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                        &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}                 \\
    & 5 &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
            &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                    &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                        &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}              \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=5]{c}   High
    & 1 &   {138.0\\  $[6.9, 0, 2.6]$}
            &   {79.3\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$}
                &   {79.7\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$}
                    &   {79.5\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$}
                        &   {79.8\\  $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$}    \\
    & 2 &   {104.96   $[6.8, 0, 6.0]$}
            &   {61.5     $[2.9, 0, 4.4]$}
                &   {61.6\\  $[3.0, 0, 4.4]$}
                    &   {59.9\\  $[2.6, 0, 3.9]$}
                        &   {61.0\\  $[2.9, 0, 4.5]$}     \\
    & 3 &   {225.5\\  $[8.9, 16.6, 2.2]$}
            &   {154.5\\  $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$}
                &   {154.7\\  $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$}
                    &   {83.0\\  $[2.9, 4.6, 2.3]$}
                        &   {79.2\\  $[3.0, 4.5, 2.1]$}      \\
    & 4 &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
            &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                    &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                        &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}                   \\
    & 5 &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
            &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                    &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}
                        &   {~\\  $[, , ]$}                   \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\SetCell[c=7]{j}   Performance metrics consist of the immediate cost and
                   [wait time of scheduled patients, number of referrals, number of rejections]
                   - average values.
    &   &   &   &   &   &                                   
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: second example]

(green lines indicates page layout)

Answer (score 1):

I have loaded `nicematrix`, replaced `tabular` by `NiceTabular`, added the key `colortbl-like` and replaced the `\multirow` by the command `\Block` provided by `nicematrix`. With the command `\multirow`, you have to specify the number of *physical* rows (and that's why you have not the expected output in your example) whereas with the command `\Block`, you specify the number of *logical* rows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison of performance metrics for heuristic scheduling rules}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{l|l|l l l l l}[colortbl-like]
    \hline
        \Block{2-1}{Inst.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Demand} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Heuristic scheduling rules} \\ \cline{3-7}
                               &  & Myopic & PPQ & DMB & AOP & EPPQ \\\hline
        \Block{5-1}{Normal} & \cellcolor{gray!30}1    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{34.1 \\ $[4.6, 0, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30} \makecell[l]{\color{blue}{11.4} \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30} \makecell[l]{18.2 \\ $[2.8, 0, 0.6]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.5 \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.5 \\ $[2.1, 0, 0.4]$} \\
                                & 2    & \makecell[l]{84.7 \\ $[6.6, 0, 3.4]$} & \makecell[l]{44.0 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$} & \makecell[l]{44.1 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.1]$} & \makecell[l]{42.8 \\ $[2.2, 0, 1.7]$} & \makecell[l]{44.3 \\ $[2.9, 0, 3.2]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}3        & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{124.6 \\ $[7.5, 11.7, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{47.3 \\ $[3.8, 6.7, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{51.9 \\ $[4.1, 7.3, 0.2]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{11.8 \\ $[2.3, 0.6, 0.3]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{12.4 \\ $[2.4, 1.0, 0.4]$} \\
                               &  4    & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\
                               &  \cellcolor{gray!30}5    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\\hline
        \Block{5-1}{High} & 1    & \makecell[l]{138.0 \\ $[6.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.3 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.7 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$} & \makecell[l]{79.5 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.6]$} & \makecell[l]{79.8 \\ $[2.9, 0, 2.7]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}2    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{104.96 \\ $[6.8, 0, 6.0]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.5 \\ $[2.9, 0, 4.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.6 \\ $[3.0, 0, 4.4]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{59.9 \\ $[2.6, 0, 3.9]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{61.0 \\ $[2.9, 0, 4.5]$} \\
                                & 3        &  \makecell[l]{225.5 \\ $[8.9, 16.6, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{154.5 \\ $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{154.7 \\ $[4.9, 16.2, 2.2]$} & \makecell[l]{83.0 \\ $[2.9, 4.6, 2.3]$} & \makecell[l]{79.2 \\ $[3.0, 4.5, 2.1]$} \\
                                & \cellcolor{gray!30}4    & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \cellcolor{gray!30}\makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\
                                &  5    & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} & \makecell[l]{ \\ $[, , ]$} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\makecell[l]{Performance metrics consist of the immediate cost and [wait time of scheduled patients, number of \\ referrals, number of rejections] - average values.}}
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \label{tabCOM}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: It's interesting that I cannot get a similar outcome using overleaf! Also, would you recommend any other way of creating the table that requires less compilation? Plus, I don't want to bold the horizontal lines of the table. Thanks.

Comment: I had forgotten a line in the code. I have modified my answer.

Comment: The code of my answer compiles on Overleaf (with the version 2022 of TeXLive). Overleaf does the right number of compilations for you. The horizontal rules are not bold. In the picture I have uploaded, some rules seem bolder than others, but it's only an artifact of the screen capture.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just copied and pasted your code in an empty project, it is interesting that I still face errors: "Package nicematrix Error: The option 'colortbl-like' is unknown for the"